# why im getting OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error error while running streamlit in live server ? the code is running ok in my localhost

Tags: python, nginx, server, streamlit

Why I'm getting `OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error` while running streamlit in live server ? the code is running ok in my localhost but getting

> OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

while running on server

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone i traced the error and corrected by changing control flow of the streamlit program